# I have a problem with RSA public key in MySQL deployed on kubernetes

Tags: mysql, pyspark, rsa, azure-databricks, azure-aks

I tried to write data from Azure Databricks to a MySQL database created in aks. Every time I tried I get the error message "java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=xx.xxx.xxx.xx)(port=3306)(type=master) : Could not read server RSA public key from file : serverRsaPublicKeyFile=public_key.pem"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMGjk.png).

But I can see the public key file with the container bash

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMO98.png)

The keys was generated using "mysql_ssl_rsa_setup".

As the container has no editor, I tried to modify the mysql_config with:

echo ssl-key=/bin/private-key.pem > /bin/mysql_config
echo ssl-cert=/bin/public-key.pem > /bin/mysql_config

But I can not check if the lines are correctly applied and I sitll getting the error.

Comment: The command you used to modify the MySQL configuration echo ssl-key=/bin/private-key.pem > /bin/mysql_config seems to be incorrect because it's redirecting output to a new file rather than appending to an existing MySQL configuration file. The correct MySQL configuration file is typically my.cnf or mysqld.cnf, and you would need to append to it, not overwrite it (using >> instead of >).

Answer (score 0):

> java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=xx.xxx.xxx.xx)(port=3306)(type=master) : Could not read server RSA public key from file : serverRsaPublicKeyFile=public_key.pem

**You should add client option to your MySQL-connection string to resolve above error:**

- `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` to allow the client to automatically request the public key from the server.
- `useSSL=false` = This will disable SSL and also suppress the SSL errors

you can also see this similar [issue](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/12545) on GitHub for more understanding.